# trying to loop through html drop down

Tags: php, html

there are a few questions like this on here, but what I am wanting to do is loop through every option element and echo them out, so far it is only echoing the selected item, when Ideally I am going to loop through each item.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $st_campaigns = $_POST['campaigns'];

    foreach ($st_campaigns as $st) {
        echo $st;
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="campaigns[]" id="campaigns[]" size="15" multiple="multiple"   style="width:150">
<option>item</option>
<option>item1</option>
<option>item</option>
<option>item</option>
<option>item</option>
<option>item</option>
<option>item</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Only the selected items are submitted with the form data. If you want all of the possible select items you will need to put them in an array and then you can use that array to populate/generate the select field as well as loop through them for whatever reason after the form is submitted.

Comment: thank you, I am basically wanting to loop through every item, and inside the loop I am going to be updating some info in a database based on a list of items with the same name, so in my project this list is populated dynamically.

Comment: this worked perfectly tho, I was going to wind up putting my data in an array anyway, but I am testing stuff out statically.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a workaround.

1. Add a hidden field in your form named "options" (for example)
2. On submit, use Javascript to loop through the items and generate a string. Comma separated or JSON might be a better option. So all options whether selected or not will be in the string.
3. Change the value of the hidden field (options) to the JSON string
4. When the form submits, use php to read `$_POST['options']` instead of `campaigns`, change JSON to array (or split csv depending on what you chose) and loop through that instead.

You can always match the selected items by first looping `campaigns` and creating key values then using php `array_key_exists` to see if key exists or `in_array` if you simply add selected items to array.